# Check what comprehension list output is not None and go to the corresponding function

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am experimenting a bit with comprehension lists and was wondering if it is possible to check what image was found (only 1 CAN be found) and send the program to the function with the correct code for that number. So the program should check which input is not `None`, and continue in the corresponding function.

```
def one():
    #the program should go here if image one.png is detected
def two():
    #the program should go here if image two.png is detected
def three():
    #the program should go here if image three.png is detected
def four():
    #the program should go here if image four.png is detected

number = [pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'{nr}.png', confidence = 0.95)
                for nr in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
            ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects, just like anything else in Python. That's why you can create a dictionary, for example

```
images = {"one": one, "two": two, "three": three, "four": four}
```

and so on, and if you manage to get the name of the found image into some variable, for example `image_name`, you can then call it as

```
images[image_name]()
```

which will execute the desired function.

So alltoghether you would have

```py
images = {"one": one, "two": two, "three": three, "four": four}

number = [nr for nr in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four') if 
          pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'{nr}.png', confidence = 0.95) is not None][0]

images[number]()
```

Mind the `[0]` after the list comprehension, as we want the name, not the name inside a list, and the `()` in the end of the last line, indicating we are calling the object (function in our case).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way if those functions are methods of a class.

```py
import os


class A:
  def one():
    #the program should go here if image one.png is detected
  def two():
    #the program should go here if image two.png is detected
  def three():
    #the program should go here if image three.png is detected
  def four():
    #the program should go here if image four.png is detected


a = A()
number = "one.png"
func_name = os.path.splitext(number)[0] # Remove .png extension
f = getattr(a, "func_name")

f()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` doesn't return `None` when no match is found, it raises an `ImageNotFoundException`, and when it does find a match it returns the (left, top, width, height) info for the first instance of the image found on the screen not image name. In other words, it doesn't really much sense to use a list comprehension in this situation in my opinion.

You can streamline thing a bit by utilizing the fact that the values of a dictionary can be anything, include function objects which make looking them up given an image name up very easy. An intermediate function that calls `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` and suppresses the exceptions it raises when there's no match is also defined to provide a more convenient interface to `pyautogui`'s function.

```
import pyautogui


def one():
    print('image one.png detected')
def two():
    print('image two.png detected')
def three():
    print('image three.png detected')
def four():
    print('image four.png detected')


image_functions = {"one": one, "two": two, "three": three, "four": four}

def check_image_on_screen(image_name):
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(f'{nr}.png', confidence=0.95)
    except ImageNotFoundException:
        location = None
    if location:
        return image_name


for nr in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'):
    func = image_functions.get(check_image_on_screen(nr), None)
    if func:
        func()
        break
else:
    print('No image detected')
```